# Sagepay - which api should I use?

Tags: opayo

I try to integrate our test system with SagePay. But I've found lot of different apis and documentations for integration. I'm bit confused about it. Could you tell me which api version is most up to date and suits my needs?

I want to have recurring payment functionality without CVV resubmit.
System will be designed to work on US market.

This api have functionality which I want and it's also mentioned in some answers on stackoverflow
https://test.sagepay.com

This api is very easy to use, but I don't see recurring payment functionality (only with CVV resubmit) 
https://developer.sagepayments.com

There is another set of documents for integration, based on .vsp services
www.sagepay.co.uk/support/integration-kits-protocols-document

I suppose some of those apis are legacy and are maintained for some old integrated systems. It would be great if documentation for those apis were gathered in one place and explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sage Pay UK and Sage Payment Solutions(US) operate independtly to each other with different integration methods and API's. www.sagepay.co.uk/support/integration-kits-protocols-document relates to Sage Pay UK only.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try to contact US team